# OBS on "Window Capture (X composite)" only shows red screen

Tags: virtualbox, desktop-recording, obs-studio

When I chose "Window Capture (X composite)" mode on OBS, and select the running Windows 10 VirtualBox, I get a red screen:

[image: Virtual Box]

It works fine with Spotify:

[image: Spotify]

I can record the whole screen, but I'd like to be able to select the window so I can resize it and if I need to bring another window in front of it.

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 with nVidia drivers - version 355.11. I will update to 364.15 if needed, but I'd rather not have to.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem with the difference that no program works for me at all. All of them only get me a red screen. However the cursor is added fine ... Is there a solution yet?